Numerical integration of iterative form
I have the following code:
       u[0, t_, h_] := 0; For[k = 1, k < 11,u[k, t_, h_] = 
       u[k - 1, t, h] +h Integrate[(D[u[k - 1, \[Tau], h], \[Tau]] + 
       u[k - 1, \[Tau], h]^2 - 1), {\[Tau], 0, t}]; 
       Print["k=", k, "____", 0 Expand[u[k, t, h]]]; k++]
           

I want to calculate the integral numerically as it is time consuming by increasing the loop.

Have you tried NIntegrate, Mathematica's numerical integration command?

No sir, could please help me to do it?

Your recent edit has significantly changed the question, pleasse avoid that. If you have a new question, consider posting a separate question. And, we already have quite a few posts about Simpson's rule: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=simpson+rule Please have a look.

@user62716 Which original question led you to the code? Do you try to solve an integral-equation? If yes please show this equation too. Thanks!

Use Memoization, it become much faster.
u[0, t_, h_] := 0;
u[k_, t_, h_] := u[k, t, h] = u[k - 1, t, h] + 
      h* Integrate[(D[u[k - 1, τ, h], τ] + u[k - 1, τ, h]^2 - 1), {τ, 0, t}]

data = Table[u[k, t, h], {k, 1, 5}]

To speed it up more, you can use numerical values for t,h like this
u[0,t_,h_]:=0;
u[k_,t_,h_]:=u[k,t,h]=u[k-1,t,h]+h* Integrate[(D[u[k-1,τ,h],τ]+u[k-1,τ,h]^2-1),{τ,0,t}];
t=1;h=3;
data=Table[u[k,t,h],{k,1,11}]//N


Which took less than one minute.  For k=9 it took little over one second.
u[0, t_, h_] := 0;
u[k_, t_, h_] := 
  u[k, t, h] = 
   u[k - 1, t, h] + 
    h* Integrate[(D[u[k - 1, \[Tau], h], \[Tau]] + 
        u[k - 1, \[Tau], h]^2 - 1), {\[Tau], 0, t}];
t = 1; h = 3;
Timing[ Table[N@u[k, t, h], {k, 1, 9}]]



Dear Nasser, still time consuming when  k,1,10

@user62716 plugin values for t and h. You have to do this any way if you want to do numerical integration.

I need it depend on h, later I will evaluate h.

@user62716 but then you can not do numerical integration if h remain symbol. Will not work.

is there any way to make faster depend on t, h?

@user62716 I do not know other way to speed it up other than using numerical values for t,h. It takes one second run for k=9 with numerical values. So you can vary h and try new values since it is very fast. Make plot etc.. to see how it changes with h ?

the value of h i have to calculate it later, however, the t  from 0 to 2

If you split up your integral, and make some observations about Integrate[u[-1 + k, t, h]^2, t] always being zero at t=0 you can simplify your expression to:
u[0, t_, h_] := 0;
u[k_, t_, h_] := u[k, t, h] =
  (1 + h) u[-1 + k, t, h] + 
   h ((Integrate[u[-1 + k, τ, h]^2, τ] /. τ -> t) - t)


Which takes a little over a minute to calculate to kMax = 9: (k = 10 seem to be a lot harder, the LeafCount of the DownValues stored in u is starting to get huge):
kMax = 9;
(*preload values*)
u[kMax, t, h]; // AbsoluteTiming

uDat = u[#, t, h] & /@ Range[0, kMax];


{72.2118, Null}

Compare this to the original:
uOrig[0, t_, h_] := 0; 
For[k = 1, k <= kMax, 
  uOrig[k, t_, h_] = 
   uOrig[k - 1, t, h] + 
    h Integrate[(D[uOrig[k - 1, \[Tau], h], \[Tau]] + 
        uOrig[k - 1, \[Tau], h]^2 - 1), {\[Tau], 0, t}];
  Print["k=", k, "____", 0 Expand[uOrig[k, t, h]]]; 
  k++] // AbsoluteTiming


{145.233, Null}

And of course verify our simplification is correct (I only verify up to k=8, because the k=9 case was taking too long to simplify):
origDat = uOrig[#, t, h] & /@ Range[0, kMax];
FullSimplify[Most@origDat == Most@uDat]


True


Can we evaluate it using say simpson...etc?
